# Adjusting initial position of PNotify notification

Tags: jquery, css, pnotify

I am trying to adjust the initial position of my PNotify notification. As you can see in the image, the notification blocks my search bar. I would like to bring the initial position of the notification down by around 50px so it doesn't block the search bar.

I've been Googling this issue for a long time now, but with no result:

I've tried:

1. Changing the CSS of the notification by adding a `margin-top: 50px`
2. Under the [docs](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/#demos-modules) there are custom classes to change the initial position, but they were all custom-defined classes like `stack_bar_top` or `stack_bar_bottom`. I would like to adjust these values myself.
3. This answer on the [Github](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/issues/46) page but I was thrown the `no such class as pnotify.css` error

[image]

This is my code for PNotify at the moment:

```
    function notification(text, type) {
        new PNotify({
            text: text,
            type: type,
            animation: 'slide',
            delay: 3000,
            top:"500px",
            min_height: "16px",
            animate_speed: 400,
            text_escape: true,
            nonblock: {
                nonblock: true,
                nonblock_opacity: .1
            },
            buttons: {
                show_on_nonblock: true
            },
            before_open: function(PNotify){
                PNotify.css({
                    "top":"50px"
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I checked out the CSS, and it seems `ui-pnotify` is in charge of the positioning. The default is `top: 25px`.

I made a new class in my CSS and called it:

```
.ui-pnotify {
  top: 50px;
}
```

Didn't seem to work, however.

Comment: inspect the css that applies to the element itself in browser console. See what rules actually apply to it ( can see all rules for any specific element) and adjust accordingly. Assume that all inline styles are script generated and the others should be in css file

Comment: I tried all that and more =/ The solution posted in the Github issues thread is outdated and no longer works either in the newer versions of PNotify.

Answer (score 2):

Download the [last version](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/) of pnotify and modify the style of the selector `.ui-pnotify` in the the css file (in my case I use pnotify.custom.min.css) with the next code:

```
.ui-pnotify {
      top: 50px;/*Replace the 25px with the top that you need*/
      right:25px;
      position:absolute;
      height:auto;
      z-index:9999
    }
```

Comment: If you have several notifications, they are placed on top of each other with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration, set the `firstpos1` variable.

So when you define your stack, it might look like this:

```
const defaultStack = {
    dir1: 'down',
    dir2: 'left',
    firstpos1: 50, // This is the initial position of the first popup relative to dir1
    firstpos2: 20,
    spacing1: 10,
    spacing2: 10,
    push: 'top',
    overlayClose: true,
    modal: false,
    context: document.body
};
```

Source: [PNotify GitHub page](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/blob/master/README.md#Stacks)

Comment: Thanks but this is almost five years agooooo man! Haha.